# About installation of Cakephp framework

Tags: php, cakephp

Hello I am new to cakePHP framework,I had set Security.salt and Security.cipherSeed,I had also configured the database Successfully,I have never know what should be done further ,to which page ,and how to see the changed effect on screen.

Comment: Use this link to install cake php. This is useful https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-cakephp-on-an-ubuntu-12-04-vps

Answer (score 0):

If You don't see read messages on Cake then works good.

Fisrt step You can edit the Home page (on app/Views/Pages/home.ctp), but this is static content and edit Your layout (on app/View/Layouts/default.ctp).

Next step will be read article/tutorial about creating Your first app: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples.html